# Not able to set a github environment variable in github actions

Tags: github, environment-variables, github-actions, aws-cli

My workflow is using a windows runner.

The workflow runs an aws cli command to get instance IDs. I then try to set the returned IDs as a github environment variable to use in future steps

Here is the snippet from my workflow file:

```
    - name: Get IDs
      id: get_instances
      run: |
        $getinfo = aws ec2 describe-instances --filters 'Name=tag:Name,Values=project-bell' --output text --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].InstanceId' --region "eu-west-1" 
        $instances = ($getinfo -Join " ")
        echo $instances
        echo "INSTANCE_ID=$instances" >> $GITHUB_ENV

    - name: Print IDs
      run: |
        echo {{ env.INSTANCE_ID }}
        echo "{{ env.INSTANCE_ID }}"
```

So the 1st line in my run command of the "Get IDs" step returns the IDs as an array. So `$getinfo` looks like this:

```
instanceID 1
instanceID 2
```

2nd line I use `-Join` command to get the IDs to be returned in a single line: `instanceID 1 instanceID 2`

I then try and set this single line as a github environment variable but it isn's working and not sure why.

When i echo $instances i can see that the -Join command has worked and i see the IDs printed as a single line `instanceID 1 instanceID 2`.

But on the "Print IDs" step `{{ env.INSTANCE_ID }}`  is returned rather than the `instanceID 1 instanceID 2` which i tried to set as a github environment variable in the previous step.

Notes:

- I have to 2 echos on the "Print IDs" job as i was just testing if i needed quotations for it to work"
- I have the -join command because when i tried to set $getinfo (1st run command) as a github env var i got an error saying it was an array

**Question**

Am I writing the command wrong to set github env?

Or is it something to do with the values themselves - like does it need to be a string?

Comment: What shell are you using in your run steps? The default is Bash, but your code would not work with Bash.

Comment: hey @BenjaminW. thanks for getting back to me - I'm using a windows runner so the default for run commands is powershell. Do i need to be using bash to set github envs? I can have a look at finding the bash equivalent of my current code if i have to

Comment: @BenjaminW. you were right about the shell. I found another post and for powershell you have to set it as ">> $env:GITHUB_ENV" and then call it later as echo $env:INSTANCE_ID . I was just really stupid and didnt change the github docs from bash to powershell - thank you!